# Calculate time of processing a rule and use in progress-bar

Tags: c#

I have created a program that uploads a file in server using ftp. Now I want to use a progress bar when file uploading in server.  Means when file is upload progress bar start with value=0 when upload doing his work value of progress bar increase and when upload done value be max and then return to default;

i have no problem with upload just i dont know how to use progress bar when i uploading a file in server.

please help me.

[my program picture](http://cyourelease.ir/wp-content/uploads/program%20for%20upload%20with%20ftp.jpg)

> ```
>    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
>         {
>             backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
>             Upload(@openFileDialog1.FileName);
>         }
>         else
>         { }
> ```

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {

            Thread.Sleep(2);

            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

        this.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: When you load a file you can get the file's size from the FileInfo say X.  Then you can create a buffer to move the file with a standard buffer size Z. Then chunk percent is Z/X*100 each time you flush the stream after writing the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a program I use that processes a dynamic amount of parts and reports the progress. Hope it helps!

Here is the end of my part processing method:

```
int Progress = Convert.ToInt16(((Convert.ToDecimal(intCounter) / Convert.ToDecimal(txtPartsList.Lines.Count()))) * 100);
bw.ReportProgress(intCounter);
```

and the code for my progress changed handle:

```
private void bwExecuteProcess_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int Progress = Convert.ToInt16(Math.Floor(((Convert.ToDecimal(e.ProgressPercentage) / Convert.ToDecimal(txtPartsList.Lines.Count()))) * 100));
    lblTotal.Text = string.Format("Total Processed: {0} of {1}", e.ProgressPercentage, txtPartsList.Lines.Count());
    lblReaderTime.Text = string.Format("Time Elapsed (sec): {0}", (swMainProcess.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000));
    pgsMain.Value = Progress;

    lblPercentComplete.Text = string.Format("Percent Complete: {0}%", Progress);
    ttpMain.SetToolTip(pgsMain, string.Format("{0}% Complete", Progress));
}
```